# Displaying images in html - Django

Tags: python, django

I have a little problem, and I dont have idea why my project doesn't work how I want. I have a **models.py**

```
class Strona(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name="Tytuł", help_text="Podaj tytuł artykułu")
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, verbose_name="Adres url SEO", help_text="Automatycznie tworzony przyjazny adres URL")
    content = HTMLField(verbose_name="Treść artykułu", help_text="Wypełnij treścią artykułu")
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='blog_images',verbose_name="Obrazek", help_text="Załącz obraz")
```

and in **view.py** I have

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Strona

def strona_glowna(request):
    strona_glowna = Strona.objects.all()
    context = {'strona_glowna': strona_glowna}
    return render(request, 'strona/index.html', context=context)
```

After that I've create the html file and include inside a code :

```
...
    {% for strona in strona_glowna %}
    <strong>{{strona.title}}</strong><br>
    {% if strona.image == True %}
    <img src="{{strona.image.url}}"><br>
    {% else %}
    {% endif %}
    <p>{{strona.content|safe}}<p></p>
    {% endfor %}    
...
```

in **setting.py** I declared:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

And the problem is, when I reload a website the images doesn't show. I think the routing for upload is ok, but I don't know why I can't display the images. Any ideas?

Updated

[image]

EDIT:

When I added in myapp/urls.py the code:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.strona_glowna, name="strona_glowna"),
]
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and set in setting.py the code:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
ENV_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(ENV_PATH, '/static/') 
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(ENV_PATH, '/media/') 
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
```

the django responde me a error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/media/images/allmini.jpg
Using the URLconf defined in moja.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
[name='strona_glowna']
^static\/(?P<path>.*)$
^D\:\/media\/(?P<path>.*)$
tinymce/
The current path, media/images/allmini.jpg, didn't match any of these.
```

Mayby You know where is a bug - I can't find it...
In google chrome inspector the path is :

```
<img src="images/allmini.jpg">
```

Comment: The src is wrong, your images are under media/blog_images and django is searching under media/images! you need to change that url o change the folder of the images

Comment: No alessio I've change the path from blog_images to images in my model.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have `{% load static %}` add it on top of your html file, then in your settings.py add the `MEDIA_ROOT` with the full path to your media folder, for example this is my `MEDIA_ROOT`:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/images/')
```

And this is my `MEDIA_URL`:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/'
```

EDIT:

the field in my model:

```
profile_picture = models.ImageField(
    upload_to=get_user_upload_path, default=os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, "profile_picture.png"),
    blank=True, null=True
)
```

the method for uploading the image to the field:

```
def get_user_upload_path(instance, filename):
    """ Crea il percorso ed il nome del file per l'upload. """
    # Recupero l'estensione dell'immagine.
    extension = filename.split('.')[-1]
    filename_no_ext = "%s_%s_%s_%s" % ('img', instance.first_name, instance.last_name, instance.pk)
    filename = "%s_%s_%s_%s.%s" % ('img', instance.first_name, instance.last_name, instance.pk, extension)
    # Elimino la vecchia immagine del profilo.
    try:
        os.remove(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, "users/", "%s.%s" % (filename_no_ext, "jpg")))
    except OSError:
        pass
    try:
        os.remove(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, "users/", "%s.%s" % (filename_no_ext, "jpeg")))
    except OSError:
        pass
    try:
        os.remove(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, "users/", "%s.%s" % (filename_no_ext, "png")))
    except OSError:
        pass
    # Ritorno il percorso completo del file.
    return os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, "users/", filename)
```

Like this the user profile image will be save in `projectname/static/images/users/filename`

EDIT:

If you don't have it add this to your urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
]
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: I have added {%load staticfiles%} in the top of my html file. This is a landing page so thats why I didn't paste the all code

Comment: I made it.. but still nothing :(

Comment: @killerbees If you are using Chrome use the inspector to see if the image is pointing to the exact location! if not check which is the correct path for the image by using the browser itself!

Comment: I've use a inspector and also in command prompt I have a 404 error. The paths what I used are: 1st I used only blog_images and 2nd time I used a public/media/blog_images. In this both cases this same problem 404..

Comment: Did you add the MEDIA_ROOT correctly? Can you please share your project tree and the MEDIA_ROOT?

Comment: MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(ENV_PATH, '/')

Comment: Can you please share your project tree, pointing to the image location and the settings.py?

Comment: Somewhere in your settings.py you should have a BASE_DIR variable, please update MEDIA_ROOT to os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'public/media/blog_images/') and MEDIA_URL to '/' then go with inspector and tell me which url you obtain for the image (you should obtain the full pishical path to your image), for example this is my BASE_DIR=os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))

Comment: I've change how You say in media root and in inspector I have the href like this: <img src="/public/media/blog_images/pic01.jpg"> and BASE_DIR variable is: BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

Comment: You said you used {% load staticfiles %} but I cannot see any staticfiles folder, before I asked you if you already used the collectstatic command, maybe you didn't

Comment: I have a path like /public/static/ but also I have seperated public/media. Maybe the /media/ folder must be in public/static/media/blog_images/*.jpg ?

Comment: in my project i have a image folder inside static (so is project/static/images) and my variables in settings are: MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/images/')
MEDIA_URL = '/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')], the image correctly show with an src of the full path to the image

Comment: And when You creating a clas in models what a path You created like image = models.FileField(upload_to ='?') where is upload?

Comment: alessioferri20 witch answer?:)

Comment: @killerbees I've edited my initial answer! the one where you start commeting on

Comment: Ok now I saw. But I don't want to upload a images from user level. Only from admin. That's why I think I dont need to create a function. Only model, register it in admin, and display by QuerySet

Comment: @killerbees The one i provided is only a ImageField in a model, you can do the same for another model if you want! It will work in the admin

Comment: and add (upload_to='images') ??

Comment: @killerbees upload_to is the file path where you want to upload the image

Comment: Ok now its clear. Please tell me in urls.py its enough to add only a clear path or I must to add also extra command to show the url for media files?

Comment: @killerbees in the urls.py what?

Comment: Now I dont have the access to my project because Iam outside and exacly I dont remember the code.but I saw in some examples something like this: path (''...), + STATIC ...

Comment: @killerbees A yes, sorry, I thought you had it already, you need to add that to your urls, i will edit my answer to add this piece of code ;)

Comment: Ok alessioferri20 please let me know if you add this code of url :)

Comment: @killerbees I've added it to my answer

Comment: Ok I will check this solution when I be in my house.

Comment: I've update my question, check it maybe You know what I'am making wrong

Answer (score 0):

To access the image in template use:

{{ strona.image }}. strona.image would not have a key named `url`.

*Note*: strona.image value would be a URL itself. You can check that by printing it in a different tag.